# Bug in implementation of Microsoft VBA compression algorithm

Tags: c#, algorithm

### Introduction

I've been writing some code to compress/decompress VBA code in Microsoft Office files.  Micorosoft have published a specification for the algorithm used including pseudocode (See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd923471(v=office.12).aspx)).  My implementation is in C# which I have [posted to GitHub](https://github.com/rossknudsen/Kavod.Vba.Compression).

The decompression algorithm seems to be working correctly, however I'm having trouble with the compression.  I believe that I have followed the pseudocode to the letter but I get different results to the examples given in the specification as well as samples I've extracted from actual Office documents.

The compression algorithm is a kind of Run Length Encoding, where copy tokens can be used to represent byte sequences found earlier in the data.  The trouble I'm having is, that as you get further into the data, there are more than one equivalent place you can use as the copy location.  I.e. the same sequence of bytes occurs in several places so there are multiple equivalent copy tokens you could accept.

Based on the provided algorithm, you should start at the current encoding position and move backwards looking for the longest sequence that could be encoded at that position.  To me it seems logical that if you have multiple equal length copy tokens, that you would either take the first one you come across (if you don't replace your best match each time you find an equivalent token) or the last one you come across (if you replace it each time).  What I'm finding is that the sample provided by Microsoft seems to pick one of the middle alternatives and I can't figure out why.

### Example - failing unit test

To explain futher, have a look at [this unit test](https://github.com/rossknudsen/Kavod.Vba.Compression/blob/master/src/Kavod.Vba.Compression.Tests/CompressionExamples.cs#L83):

```
public void CompressionProducesExpectedOutput()
{
    CompressionTestHelper.LowLevelCompressionComparison(_expectedDecompressedBytes, _expectedCompressedBytes);
}

public static void LowLevelCompressionComparison(byte[] decompressedBytes, byte[] expectedCompressedBytes)
{
    var refCompressed = new CompressedContainer(expectedCompressedBytes);
    var decompressed = new DecompressedBuffer(decompressedBytes);
    var sutCompressed = new CompressedContainer(decompressed);

    var refTokens = GetTokensFromCompressedContainer(refCompressed).OfType<CopyToken>().ToList();
    var sutTokens = GetTokensFromCompressedContainer(sutCompressed).OfType<CopyToken>().ToList();

    //Assert.Equal(refTokens.Count, sutTokens.Count);
    for (var i = 0; i < refTokens.Count; i++)
    {
        var expected = refTokens[i];
        var actual = sutTokens[i];
        Assert.Equal(expected, actual);
    }
}

private static IEnumerable<IToken> GetTokensFromCompressedContainer(CompressedContainer refCompressed)
{
    var refTokens = from c in refCompressed.CompressedChunks
        from s in ((CompressedChunkData)c.ChunkData).TokenSequences
        from t in s.Tokens
        select t;
    return refTokens;
}
```

Basically this code takes a the expected decompressed input, compresses it and gets the token sequence.  It also takes the expected compressed output, deserialises it and gets the token sequence.  Then compares the sequences.  The full source is available at the GitHub repo linked above.

### Calculation by hand

In this unit test the raw data is `#aaabcdefaaaaghijaaaaaklaaamnopqaaaaaaaaaaaarstuvwxyzaaa`.  You can see that the `a`'s are the only repeated character.  Since the algorithm uses 2 bytes to encode a copy token, if there are 3 or more bytes that are repeated it is efficient to use a copy token (otherwise literal tokens are used instead).  So the last 3 `a`'s in the input will be replaced with a copy token.

The expected compressed output is:

```
private const string ExpectedCompressedOutput =
    "01 2F B0 00 23 61 61 61 62 63 64 65 82 66 00 70 61 67 68 69 6A 01 38 08 61 6B 6C 00 30 6D 6E 6F" +
    "70 06 71 02 70 04 10 72 73 74 75 76 10 77 78 79 7A 00 3C";
```

This byte sequence has come straight out of the specification.  Ignoring details, the last two bytes (`00 3C`) are the final copy token.  If we expand out the bits (16 bit, unsigned, little endian), we get:

```
00 3C:   0011 1100 0000 0000
```

The algorithm says to calculate the length and offset (see 2.4.1.3.19.2 Unpack CopyToken):

```
difference = 53
bitcount = 6
length mask = 0000 0000 0011 1111
offset mask = 1111 1111 1100 0000
encoded =     0011 1100 0000 0000
length =      0000 0000 0000 0000 + 3 = 3
offset =     (0011 1100 0000 0000 >> 10) + 1
       =      0000 0000 0000 1111 + 1
       =      16
```

So the length is correct (3 bytes) but the offset selects a sequence starting 16 bytes before the position that the sequence is to be copied to, which is right in the middle of the long sequence of `a`'s.  In my implementation, I get 12 as the offset.

If anyone can point out an error in my code, that would be great.  Alternatively, if I have got it implemented correctly, can anyone figure out how MS are selecting their copy sequence?

### What I'm looking to achieve

As pointed out by @JeroenMostert, I haven't been clear on what I want to know.  I would like to produce a compressor which produces the same compressed output as the Microsoft implementation.  Thats the ultimate, as I will learn what I did wrong and also eliminate a potential source of error in a larger piece of software that this codebase is used in.

Failing that, if I can't get an exact match, maybe confirmation that I do have **a** valid implementation rather than **the** valid implementation will be enough.  Certainly I need to do some more testing with my larger codebase to see if my compressed output can actually be read by MS Software.

Comment: Is your question about why different implementations could choose different compressed sequences that still decode to the same decompressed sequence? Because that doesn't sound like a bug to me, at worst an overly explicit specification. There's nothing unusual (in general) about compressors having choices about how they compress, that's a quality of implementation issue (or sometimes a size versus speed tradeoff). Can sequences compressed by you be read successfully by MS software and vice versa?

Comment: @JeroenMostert edited answer with a response to your comments.  If you want to add an answer that partially addresses some of these points, I'm happy to upvote/give-credit.  I'm keen to learn as well as solve the actual problem :D

Comment: I'm not sure there *is* a problem. One issue you can run into if you commit yourself to byte-for-byte compatibility with MS is that the compressor used might change in the next release, since MS itself is probably not committed to that. The pseudocode should probably not be taken as a formal definition of the algorithm you *must* use, merely as *a* compressor that will produce valid output. (Disclaimer: I haven't actually verified if your output complies with the specification, so I'm not posting this as an answer.)